# javascript validate and validate on click or enter

Tags: javascript, authentication, keyboard

I have a login script date validates on clicking the submit button.

```js
    // Below function Executes on click of login button.
    function validate(){
        var password = document.getElementById("passid").value;
        if ( password == "thisisthepassword"){
            window.location = "loggedin.html"; // Redirecting to other page.
            return false;
        }
    }
```

```html
    <form id="code" method="post">
    <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="password" name="passid" id="passid""></div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="button" value="Login" id="submit" onclick="validate()" style="border: none;">Login</button></div>
    </form>
```

Now I want this script to also run when the enter key is pressed after entering the code, but none of the examples I find seems to work in combination with what I already have

Comment: Are you trying to run the `validate` function every time the user presses the key on the keyboard?

Comment: The first thing to do is remove the `onClick` from the button and move the validation check to the `onSubmit` property in `form`. That will allow enter to work as expected. Check out the example from W3: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp

Comment: I moved the validate to the form:
<form onsubmit="validate()">
and removed it from the button and made it type=submit. Now the script runs only when i press enter and only for wrong password, if its right nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you can change the button type to submit, and use
onsubmit="validate()" event on the form element instead of the onclick event that you are using on the button

Answer (score 0):

See the snippet below, I've added an event listener that will trigger a button click when enter is pressed. This will still run the same validation that occurs when you click the button.

```js
function validate() {
  var password = document.getElementById("passid").value;
  if (password == "thisisthepassword") {
    window.location = "loggedin.html"; // Redirecting to other page.
    return false;
  }
}

//This code will trigger a button click when "enter" is pressed.
var input = document.getElementById("passid");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  // keyCode 13 is the "Enter" key on the keyboard
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    // Prevent default action
    event.preventDefault();
    // Trigger the button element with a click
    document.getElementById("submit").click();
  }
});
```

```html
<form id="code" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="password" name="passid" id="passid" "></div>
<div class="form-group ">
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-block " type="button " value="Login " id="submit " onclick="validate() " style="border: none; ">Login</button></div>
</form>
```

Comment: I used this code now, but then nothing runs. Does it matter that the script is in an external file? called in the header?

Comment: If you are calling the script from an external file, make sure that you're calling it before the closing `</body>` tag. This will ensure that all DOM elements have loaded before you run your script.